# Packages with no name listed by yum

Tags: yum, fedora, rpm, package-management

In my Fedora 20 system I see these two packages with no names (and with no version one):

```
[user@notebook ~]$ sudo yum list installed|grep rawhide
                               0.10.23-2.fc19       @rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide  
                                                    @rpmfusion-free-rawhide
```

And in Yum Extender they are absent.
How can them to find, delete, fix?

Comment: you can use "rpm -qa | grep rawhide". The version is always informed in the rpm package name. And you can use rpm -e to remove it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be seeing packages that have really long names or versions.  These will wrap to a second line.  If so, `grep` is only picking up the second line.  Try running `grep` with listing the previous line too:

```
yum list installed | grep -B1 rawhide
```

Answer (score 2):

Using grep on yum output could lead to such kind of results. That's an extract from my yum output:

```
...
libnl.x86_64           1.1-14.el6       @base
libogg.x86_64          2:1.1.4-2.1.el6  @base
libpcap.x86_64         14:1.0.0-6.20091201git117cb5.el6
                                        @base
libpciaccess.x86_64    0.13.1-2.el6     @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
libselinux.x86_64      2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1
                                        @base
...
```

As you can see, if you grep on the word `base`, you'll get two lines with just `@base`

My suggestion is to grep on the name of the package you are looking for or pipe the output to less and than look for the word *rawhide*:

`sudo yum list installed | less`  Then /rawhide